# Intelligent addition of words to make a question from the statement

Tags: logic, nlp-question-answering

I have 5000 videos and I want to add words in front of it, to make a question out of the title.
For eg. Video title is 
 1. 'Historian era' I want a question out of it - What is Historian era 
 2. 'Solve using Quadratic Equation' - 'How to solve using quadratic equation'

Answer (score 0):

My bet:

I would analyze the first word of the title.

If it is a verb, then add 'How to ' in front of it, for example.

For knowing what the first word actually is, I would check them against an API, such as: https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/

Then you can act accordingly.